# Invalid or corrupt jarfile error

Tags: raspbian

I try to run a jar file with my Raspberry Pi which has Raspbian OS. First I followed these instructions

https://wiki.debian.org/Java/

from that page I run ;

```
apt-get install default-jre
```

and

```
apt-get install default-jdk
```

After succesful operations I try to open a jar file (which is succesfully opened in my Windows OS computer) with this from terminal;

```
sudo java -jar myJarFile.jar
```

it is not opened and gives and error like

**Invalid or corrupt jarfile myJarFile.jar**

So, what is the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not sure if this is that much raspberry pi based.

Comment: yes it is. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah I know you are running it on raspbian and are using the raspberry pi but I mean that the problem may not have anything to do with the raspbery pi. Maybe it's something with Linux in general?

Comment: Have you tried recreating it from source on the pi to see what happens?  If you don't have the source, where is the `.jar` from?

Comment: No. Just found a runnable .jar file and try to run.

Comment: Just to be clear , i wrote a simple code with java and it has a GUI, it  compiles and runs perfectly.

Comment: What does `jar tf myJarFile.jar` say?  If you rename it as zip, what does your zip program say? Maybe it doesn't have a proper manifest?

Comment: @francis it throws `java.util.zip.ZipException : error in opening zip file`

Comment: The jar file really does sound broken. Have you edited it manually?  I'm surprised that your windows computer manages to run it then, if you're 100% sure that it's the same file and hasn't been damaged by copying.

Comment: Maybe. I will try to get a .jar file from my own .

Answer (score 1):

From what you say, it sounds like your jar file is corrupt.  Maybe it got corrupted on download, or when copying it.  Maybe you opened the jar, edited a file and then reconstructed the jar.  Maybe you just zipped up the .class files and renamed it to jar.

My guess is that on your windows machine it's working but you're not running the same jar, or not running a jar at all.  You say you "wrote a simple code with java", but also that you "Just found a runnable .jar file".  You're not clear.

Copy the .class files to the pi and run those instead, or make a proper jar file and make sure you test the jar file thoroughly on your windows machine before transferring to the pi.  If it works on one it should work on the other.